# Can't update rules with chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is my code for 'popup.js', I'm trying to add a dynamic rule by pressing the save button in the extension's popup but webstorm indicates that this rule array is not of type Rule[]. Ignoring Webstorm and trying to use this I get this error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Internal error while updating dynamic rules.` Any ideas?

```
const saveButton = document.getElementById("save")

saveButton.addEventListener('click',() => {
    console.log(document.getElementById('domain').value)
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(
        {
            addRules: [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "priority": 1,
                    "action": {
                        "type": "redirect",
                        "redirect": {
                            "regexSubstitution": document.getElementById('domain').value
                        }
                    },
                    "condition": {
                        "regexFilter": "www.youtube.com",
                        "resourceTypes": [
                            "main_frame"
                        ],
                        "excludedDomains": [document.getElementById('domain').value]
                    }
                }
            ]
         }
    )
})
```

Comment: Maybe there are uppercase letters or spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I copied that rule from my rules.json file that works as a static rule when I use it on the manifest file. The problem is that I can't add or remove rules with the method mentioned in my issue.

Comment: I mean the text that you get from `document`. Never trust the input data.

Comment: See also https://crbug.com/1228675